# Bad request While Sending multipart/form-data to mvc controller using dynamically created HTML form

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data

I have read all related question on all the portals since 2 days but i aint able to fix this issue , please look into this.

I have created a dynamic html form :

```
 var jsprintId = "@Model.print.Id";
        function DisplayIfExists(jsimageType, reqdiv) {
            var d = document.getElementById(reqdiv);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { printId: jsprintId, imageType: jsimageType },
                url: '/Prints/'+jsprintId+'/Image/'+jsimageType,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "NoImage") {
                        d.innerHTML = "<form method='POST' action='http://localhost:5000/Prints/"+jsprintId+"/edit/UploadPrintImage' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='frmUploadIconImage'>" +
                            "<h1 style='text-transform:capitalize;margin-left:15px'>" + jsimageType + " Image</h1>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='printId' value='"+jsprintId+"'>"+
                            "<div class='row' style='margin: 1em -1em;'>" +
                            "<div class='col-md-10' style= 'padding: 0; overflow:hidden;'>" +
                            "<label type= 'text' class='form-control txtbox' id= 'lbl_svg_icon' style= 'margin-left:27px;height:34px'> Icon Image (SVG)</label>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<label class='btn btn-primary' for='svg_file_icon'>Browse<input type='file' name='svg_file_icon' id='svg_file_icon'  style='display:none'/></label>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='row text-center'>" +
                            "<input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Upload' id='btnUploadSubmit'/>" +
                            "</div>"
                        "</form>";
                    }
                    else {
                        d.innerHTML = "<img src='" + response + "' style='width:150px'> "
                    }
                }
            })

        }
```

and my function for Sending this post request is :

```
$(function(){
                $("#tabs-test").on('submit', '#frmUploadIconImage', function (form) {
                    form.preventDefault();
                    var data = new FormData(this);
                    if (iconImageValid) {
                        for (var key of data.entries()) {
                            console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("UploadPrintImage", "Prints"))',
                            data: data,
                            method: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            success: function (response) {
                                DisplayIfExists(jsimageType, "tabs-test");
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log('your problem is ' + error.statusText);
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("You can upload only SVG files");
                        $("#lbl_svg_icon").parent().addClass("has-error");
                        $("#lbl_svg_icon").text("SVG File");
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
```

the error I get is a bad request , my controller action is :

```
 [HttpPost("Prints/{printId}/edit/UploadPrintImage")]
 [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPrintImage(IFormCollection form)
    {
      //my code
    }
```

it gives me the same error with all the argument type that i define i have tried the following :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPrintImage(FormCollection form);
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPrintImage(HttpContext form);
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPrintImage(HttpRequest form);
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPrintImage(string printId, IFormfile file);
```

and all possible combinations but nothing works all it gives is a 400 BAD request.

following is my request screenshot:
[image]

the same code works when i have a hardcoded html form but not with dynamically created html form.

looking forward to a working solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you try this: Let the form be created dynamically, but attach the form method and action later when the form is loaded.

If the form gets loaded when the document loads, try writing it in document.ready or else if it loads on some event, try binding it later.

Comment: I think it might be the html structure issue. Check once your dynamic html is well structured. and also check when you are assigning inner html to div which is not surrounded with another form tag

Comment: Its should be `var data = new FormData($(this).get(0));` (and do not use `IFormCollection` - your POST method should have a parameter which is a model)

Comment: are you sure that multipart maps to iformcollection? check the docs

Comment: And not related, but its just `url: '@Url.Action("UploadPrintImage", "Prints")';` - you do not need `Html.Raw()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i just tried various urls including the raw but thats not the issue as you pointed . and yes let me try with model

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama iformcollection works with basic post(without ajax) from razor to controller action for sure not sure about ajax as I am a learner here..

Comment: @sifavahora, `IFormCollection` will work for ajax as well (its just not very good practice)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh  ok Thanks , and I tried changes you suggested it is still stuck with bad request.

Comment: @programtreasures i checked that , seems to be fair as the div is emtpy before any dynamic html

Comment: @sifavahora try contentType multipart/form-data in ajax request

Comment: @programtreasures by giving content type in ajax it give me :InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary. i think it overwrites the boundary